# Twisted TLSRequired Error While Sending Mail via ESMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp, twisted, ssl

i implemented a mail sender with twisted. It it works without any error on Ubuntu, whereas when i tried to run it on a windows machine (XP), it gives TLSRequiredError.

I could not find satisfactory answer, help or comments will be appreciated.

Here is the tracceback of the error:

```
2012-12-12 11:25:10,515 MailSender: Error occured while sending mail: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.mail.smtp.TLSRequiredError'>: 502 Server does not support secure communication via TLS / SSL
<<< 250-STARTTLS
<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
<<< 250-DSN
<<< 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error occurs because, on Windows machine pyOpenSSL module is not installed.

When i install [pyOpenSSL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL), error is gone.